# GetComputerNameString Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I have a line of text in my Inno Setup file that is:

- `TextBox.Text := GetComputerNameString();`

to get the computers name. I'm getting this error when trying to go through the setup wizard once it's built:

[image]

Do I have to do some sort of code setup (like registering an external function or something) to call this function or should I just be able to call it since it's built in?

Comment: On which OS are you facing this problem?

Comment: Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard, 64 bit.

Comment: What does `GetLastError` return after trying to retrieve the computer name? http://www.vincenzo.net/isxkb/index.php?title=GetLastError_%28%29

Comment: Unknown at the moment, I shall put that in and give it a  look.

Comment: Are you sure the error is caused by the `GetComputerNameString`? Can you put `Log('Before GetComputerNameString');` before the `TextBox.Text := GetComputerNameString();` and `Log('After GetComputerNameString');` after and show us the installer log?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You declare a variable as a global variable

```
[code]
var
    glbComputerName String;

...
step by 1 function
    glbComputerName := GetComputerNameString();
    TextBox.Text := glbComputerName;
...
step by 2 function
    //glbComputerName use...
    MsgBox( 'Computer Name :' + glbComputerName, mbError, MB_OK );
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?